# Virtual Directory Authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, upload, iis-6

I am developing a application where i am performing the Download/Upload using WebClient and BITS.
i have a virtual directory in IIS6.0/7.0. i have to set the Authentication to the that directory(Id & Password). currently i m using basic IIS authentication in which we can pass id and password but using same user id and password we can login to server.

My requirement is that **if someone happens to know the username / password, they shouldn't be able to do anything else than upload and download (ie, you should not be able to log in into the server using the username and password)**

Is there is any way from we can set the ID and password on Directory level or any other alternative.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what shared hosting providers offer, but if you have root access you can create a new user that only has permissions for that specific directory. This user would not be able to login or access any other directory on the server.

Answer (score 0):

To chanmge access permission at a directory level, you simply has to change permission on file system for that directory.